# Django : Managing many forms in one view

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to handle three forms in one view. I explain : 
It's a checkout form which have a form for shipping adress, billing adress, credit card info.

My problem it's that I want to let the choice to the user to choose if the billing adress is the same of the shipping adress. I made this with a checkbox.

But now I'm stuck at the validation because of the three forms. I don't know how to handle them.

Here is my code :

```
def show_checkout(request, template_name='checkout/checkout.html'):
user = User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CheckoutForm(request.POST)
    form_adress = ShippingForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and form_adress.is_valid():
        response = process(request)
        form_adress.save(commit=False)

        if not form_adress.same_adress:
            form_adress.user_shipping = user
            form_adress.user_billing = user
        else:
            form_adress.user_shipping = user
            form_billing = BillingForm(request.POST)
            form_billing.save(commit=False)
            form_billing.user_billing = user
            form_billing.save()
        form_adress.save()
        order_number = response.get('order_number', 0)
        error_message = response.get('message', '')
        if order_number:
            request.session['order_number'] = order_number
            receipt_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_receipt')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(receipt_url)
    else:
        error_message = 'Correct the errors below'
else:
    form = CheckoutForm()
    form_adress = ShippingForm()
    form_billing = BillingForm()
    error_message = None
if cart.is_empty(request):
    cart_url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(cart_url)
page_title = 'Checkout'
return render(request, template_name, {
    'error_message': error_message,
    'page_title': page_title,
    'form': form,
    'form_adress': form_adress,
    'form_billing': form_billing,
    },
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And my template :

```
<form action="." method="post" class="row-fluid">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="adress span10">
<fieldset class="checkout" style="float:left;"> 
<legend>Shipping Info</legend>
{{ form_adress.as_p }}
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="checkout billing_adress" style="float:left;">
<legend>Billing Info</legend>
{{ form_billing.as_p }}
</fieldset>
</div>
<fieldset class="checkout row-fluid">
<legend>Credit Card Info</legend>
<table>
{% form_table_row form.name %}
{% form_table_row form.lastname %}
{% form_table_row form.credit_card_number %}
{% form_table_row form.credit_card_type %}
{% form_table_row form.credit_card_expire_month %}
{% form_table_row form.credit_card_expire_year %}
{% form_table_row form.credit_card_cvv %}
</table>
</fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Place Order" class="submit" /></th>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and my forms :

```
class ShippingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    same_adress = forms.BooleanField(required=True, label="different address for billing ?")

class Meta:
    model = Address
    exclude = 'user_billing, user_shipping'


class BillingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        exclude = 'user_billing, user_shipping'
```

For the moment I'm facing the local variable 'form_billing' referenced before assignment

Any suggestions ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I did'nt specified that the previous page is sending a POST request, that's why my form is not initializing because at the render of the page he goes into if request.method == 'POST'. I've tried to fix it with this : if request.method == 'POST' and not request.POST['submit'] == 'Checkout' (Which is the POST VALUE from the previous page

Comment: I tried this if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['submit'] == None: and the render is good but I can't pass the other validation because he don't find the key submit.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `form_billing` when `form_adress` is valid and `form_adress.same_adress` is false and `order_number` is 0.

You are referencing it in context to `render()`.

Also, looks like this if

```
if not form_adress.same_adress:
```

should be

```
if form_adress.same_adress:
```

Comment: yes, but I want to initializing only if there is same_adress checked. The other problem is that it doesn't pass the form_adress.is_valid() I've got some errors

Comment: @Pythdav, in case when `form_address` is invalid `form_billing` address is also not initialized. May be you can initialize a empty form for cases when `same_adress` is checked and pass that to template.

Comment: I did it like you said, I've pass out the form missing problem, but now he didn't recognize the value put in fields. And returns errors like nothing is filled in the form. Only the one field has value.(the first one) (Thank you :))